# What is the recommended database design for 2 entities that share most of their attributes?

Tags: database, data-modeling, finance

In a financial analysis program there is an account object, and a loan account object that extend it. The loan object only has couple more attribute than the account. Which one of the following will be the recommend DB design ?

1. Table for the account, and another table for the extra loan
   attribute with 1 to 1 relationship.
2. Two separate tables.
3. One table that has all fields, and ignore the loan attribute for
   basic account.

Answer (score 0):

You should go for first approach.
For relationship cardinality, you should consider what data will be stored in each of the object. Are you going to maintain history for it.
As per my understanding about the above said objects, you should go for one-to-many relationship.

Answer (score 0):

You're talking about implementing polymorphism, which while not possible in a relational database is a good way to assess the pros and cons.  Option 1 is similar to subclassing, where the loan account inherits everything from the account and extends it.  So use that if you want the account to be a superclass...in other words if you add a new kind of account, say credit card, you will add another table for it and have it relate to account also.  That means the account table must remain generic...account number, balance, etc.

Option 2 is treating the two types of accounts like separate classes.  Use that if they won't share many CRUD operations, because now a simple balance update in response to a transaction has to have different code somewhere.

Option 3 is the generalist approach.  It's big advantage is simplicity in modeling and querying.  It's big disadvantage is that you won't be able to implement NOT NULL constraints on columns that need to be there for some account types but not others.

There's a 4th option to combine the first 2 options which provides a solution similar to the party abstraction for people and organizations.  You have 3 tables: 1) an account table that handles the basic elements of account id, balance, owner, etc.; 2) a loan account table that has the additional columns and a reference to account id; and 3) a basic account table that just has a reference to account id.  This may seem like overkill, but it sets up a system that you can extend without modification.  I've used the pattern many times.